# Changing the format of the URL in Nette Application

Tags: nette

I am new to Nette.

I have the router set up as

`$router->addRoute('<presenter>/<action>[/<id>]', 'Home:home:default');`

In common.neon I have the mapping set to:

`*: App\Modules\*\Presenters\*Presenter`

The site is set up as modules.

In order to get to a page the URL is in the format of

`http://192.168.56.30/home.signin/`

I am wanting to change it so the format is

`http://192.168.56.30/home/signin/`

The home.signin format is also how it is presented when using the n:href in latte file

`<a class="nav-link active" n:href=":Home:Signout:default">Sign Out</a>`

this is translating to home.signout for example.

Is there a way to fix this so its in a nicer format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```php
$router->addRoute('<module>/<presenter>/<action>[/<id>]', 'Home:home:default');
```

Or you can use `$router->withModule('Home')` method (see https://doc.nette.org/en/application/routing#toc-modules for details).